# Check if all values in my array equals specific text

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I created the following code to check if a specific value exists in an array and then show text based on whether the value exists or not:

```
// Get my div
ar mydiv = document.querySelector("#mydiv");

// Create Array
var mylist =  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myitem'), e => e.innerText)

// Check if value exist
myanswer = mylist.includes("None");

// Output Text
if (myanswer == true) {
    mydiv.textContent = "True in list";
} else {
    mydiv.textContent = "False in list";
}
```

It works well, but now I want to change it so that it checks weather ALL values in my array equals "None".

I changed the following line:

```
myanswer = mylist.includes("None");
```

To be this instead:

```
myanswer = mylist.every.equals("None");
```

This doesn't work though, so how is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `myList.every(val => val === 'None')`

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `MyList.every` is a function not a single element.

What you want instead is checking if every element is equals to None.

Then The good way of doing it is the following :

```js
myList.every(elem => elem === 'None')
```

This will return `true` if all elems are equals to None, `false` otherwise

---

Here is a small example with an array of string where you want to check if every item is `'None'`

```js
const arr1 = ['None','None','None','None','Not None']
const arr2 = ['None','None','None','None','None']

console.log(arr1.every(elem => elem === 'None'))
console.log(arr2.every(elem => elem === 'None'))
```

Comment: "*The good way of doing it is ... `elem.equals('None')`*" - there is no equals method/function in JavaScript; so that would be a syntax error, surely?

Comment: Oh yes you're right, i've taken this from the question actually. I've update my answer with `===` instead